# Function to replace 3 first letter of string

Tags: scala

I've a tuples like

`{("ABC", "123"),("DEF", "456"),("GHI", "789")}`

I need a function to convert 3 first letter of string with mapping above

Sample:

```
ABC_MESSAGE1 -> 123_MESSAGE1 
DEF_MESSAGE2 -> 456_MESSAGE2
GHI_MESSAGE3 -> 789_MESSAGE3
ADF_MESSAGE4 -> ADF_MESSAGE4 ( No change )
```

How can I do that? I am new to Scala programming and would appreciate any help here.

Comment: Can you share your attempts?

Comment: Frankly, I am not familiar with Scala. I will update my solution after complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you have a list of tuples

```
val listOfTuples = List(
  ("ABC", 123),
  ("DEF", 456),
  ("GHI", 789),
)
```

Now to convert this to a map, you can write the following function

```
val endOfMap = "ADF_MESSAGE" + (listOfTuples.size + 1)

listOfTuples.zipWithIndex.map {
  case ((str, int), index) =>
    (str.take(3) + "_MESSAGE" + (index + 1)) -> (int + "_MESSAGE" + (index + 1))
}.toMap + (endOfMap -> endOfMap)
```

This will fetch you an output as

```
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(ABC_MESSAGE1 -> 123_MESSAGE1, DEF_MESSAGE2 -> 456_MESSAGE2, GHI_MESSAGE3 -> 789_MESSAGE3, ADF_MESSAGE4 -> ADF_MESSAGE4)
```

Comment: Thank. you. Appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Turn your tuples into a `Map` for easy lookup.

```
val lookup = Seq(("ABC","123"), ("DEF","456"), ("GHI","789")).toMap

Seq("ABC_MESSAGE1", "DEF_MESSAGE2", "GHI_MESSAGE3", "ADF_MESSAGE4")
  .map(msg =>lookup.get(msg.take(3)).fold(msg)(_ + msg.drop(3)))
//res0: Seq[String] = List(123_MESSAGE1, 456_MESSAGE2, 789_MESSAGE3, ADF_MESSAGE4)
```